# Xaml LeftAlt in KeyGesture not allowed

Tags: wpf, xaml, key, gesture

How I can use this key combination in XAML?

```
<RoutedUICommand x:Key="GlobalExitCommand" Text="Execute GlobalExitCommand">
            <RoutedUICommand.InputGestures>
                <KeyGesture>LeftAlt+F1</KeyGesture>
            </RoutedUICommand.InputGestures>
        </RoutedUICommand>
```

The `LeftAlt+F1` is not allowed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LeftAlt` is not a valid [ModifierKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) value. The valid values are `None`, `Alt`, `Control`, `Shift` and `Windows`.

So you can't create a `KeyGesture` that only accepts the left <kbd>ALT</kbd> in XAML. You could use `Alt` and handle the rest in your `Executed` event handler though:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="GlobalExitCommand" Text="Execute GlobalExitCommand">
        <RoutedUICommand.InputGestures>
            <KeyGesture>Alt+F1</KeyGesture>
        </RoutedUICommand.InputGestures>
    </RoutedUICommand>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource GlobalExitCommand}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

---

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```